# Using BeautifulSoup to parse and get nothing

Tags: python, post

I would like to get the web data with a selection list, like marked in picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JlmY.png)
[https://goodinfo.tw/StockInfo/ShowK_Chart.asp?STOCK_ID=3044&CHT_CAT2=DATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OSxC.png)
I observed that after choosing would trigger a link with post method.
And I used the following code to get data but nothing return.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
[enter image description here][2]
Query_Para = {
'STOCK_ID': '3044',
'CHT_CAT2': 'DATE',
'STEP': 'DATA',
'PERIOD': '180'}

headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'My User Agent99', 
        'From': 'youremail91@domain.com'
    }

res = requests.post('https://goodinfo.tw/StockInfo/ShowK_Chart.asp', data = Query_Para, headers = headers)

res.encoding = 'utf-8'
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
```

Is the web's problem or my code?
Anyway to get the data?

Please help.
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: you need to fetch the result whenever the table name in dropdown list changes

Comment: you can use `DevTool` in Chrome/Firefox to see requests from browser to server. It may send more fields in post. It may use cookies or session number. And it may need all headers - but with real values not fake `'My User Agent99'`.